# Resurrecting a 12V SLA from a UPS

Tags: batteries

Got an old 12V UPS battery, a sealed lead acid 17.2Ah battery. Quite a nice YUASA battery. Unfortunately it reads 9.92V so has been discharged badly. Is there any chance of salvaging it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does it have a bunch of specs printed on the side? Check for a manufacture date. If it's more than 3 or 4 years old, it may not be such a prize. Smaller ones (e.g. 1.5A-Hr) can become completely unable to take a charge in that amount of time. On the other hand I've seen 7A-Hr ones last more than 5 years.

I'd put it on a 12V trickle charger for a couple of days, then once the open-circuit voltage (off the charger) is 12.5 or 12.6V, put a load on it and see if the voltage sags. Use something that pulls an amp or so, and if the voltage sags more than a couple of tenths, it means the internal resistance has gone up, and the battery is just plain old.

Comment: Many UPSs in particular will eat these batteries quickly.

Comment: Specs: NP18-12B, 12V 17.2Ah, valve regulated, sealed lead-acid type, rechargeable battery, contains lead. Nothing else printed on it.

Comment: The date of manufacture may be 'melted' into the casting somewhere (not printed on a label per se.)

Comment: There's a number stamped onto the top of it, near the contacts: 01072330... does this mean anything?

Answer (score 1):

I would not care about age, however if a 12 V battery reads under 10.5 V it usually means a cell is shorted.

If you can, however, get it to like 13 V after it has been charged and the charger disconnected, then it might be possible to resurrect it by desulphating it. Sadly AGM/GEL batteries tend to be harder to desulphate than plan flooded cells but you could still give it a try.